# mikroc pic16f877A timer code not working

Tags: pic, mikroc

i wrote a code in mikroc for pic16f877A in which i have used a timer0 and timer1.
i debug my code and found that timer0 is not working but i am not able to understand the reason behind it. I even checked datasheet for the OPTION_REG 
but couldn't figure out the problem plz help. 
i am new to pic programming.
I just uploaded the function in which timer0 and timer1 is setup.
UART is used to check whether each line is getting executed and i found after printing the value of TMR1H it stops .

```
     int feedback()
     {
     sh = 0;
     UART1_WRITE_TEXT("inside feedback");
     UART1_Write(13); // newline

     TMR0=193;
     Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(TMR0);
     UART1_Write(13); // newline

     INTCON=0xA0;
     Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(INTCON);
     UART1_Write(13); // newline

     TMR1L=0;
     Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(TMR1L);
     UART1_Write(13); // newline

     TMR1H=0;
     Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(TMR1H);
     UART1_Write(13); // newline

     OPTION_REG.PSA=0;
     OPTION_REG.PS2=0;
     OPTION_REG.PS1=1;
     OPTION_REG.PS0=0;
     OPTION_REG.T0SE=0;
     OPTION_REG.T0CS=0;
     UART1_WRITE_TEXT("timer0 start");
     UART1_Write(13); // newline

     T1CON=0x07;
     UART1_WRITE_TEXT("timer1 start");
     UART1_Write(13); // newline

     sh=1;
     Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(sh);
     UART1_Write(13); // newline

    while(sh==1){
    Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(sh);
    UART1_Write(13); // newline

    UART1_WRITE_TEXT("inside while loop");
    }

    UART1_WRITE_TEXT("outside while loop");

    TMR1H=TMR1H*1000;
    sh=TMR1H+TMR1L;
    actualOut=(60*2*sh)/8;
    Uart1_Intout_ReturnInt(actualOut);
    UART1_Write(13); // newline

    return actualOut;
   }
   void interrupt(){

   T1CON=0x00;
   sh=0;

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're enabling the TMR0 interrupt in the line `INTCON=0xA0;` but I don't see an interrupt service routine for it. The interrupt is probably triggering after the lines that do work and then is remains asserted because the TMR0IF interrupt flag (INTCON bit 2) is not being cleared.